# UIView animation -- horizontal page curl... like a book?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I'm pretty sure I've run across this animation at some point, but I can't remember where or how to do it!

I want the equivalent of `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` but a full page horizontal curl. Does anybody have code that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple Documentation, it does not exist: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationTransition

Not sure whether this helps:
[iPhone Curl Left and Curl Right transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions)

Comment: I realize this, but I'm pretty sure someone has done this with just using CAAnimation

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own or use the one Claus suggested but there is no UIViewAnimationCurlHorizontal.