# Is this code, for horizontal page curl in iPhone, valid?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, page-curl

I was Googling for applying horizontal page curl in iPhone. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions), but it wasn't appropriate for me (To change orientation and work in different ori.). I tried to search the web more. Finally I got [this link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=508042). From where, I could understand the horizontal page curl.

But when I went to code deeply, I found some confusing points:

1. `extern NSString *kCAFilterPageCurl; // From QuartzCore.framework`
   is it valid to use internal variable ? ( as it's mentioned - from QuartzCore )
2. `CAFilter *previousFilter = [[CAFilter filterWithType:kCAFilterPageCurl] retain];`

   Above statement is giving warning ( not error ) -> no '+filterWithType:' method found. Might be using internal (apple's private) method.
3. `[previousFilter setDefaults];`

   Above statement is giving warning ( not error ) -> no '-setDefaults:' method found. Might be using internal (apple's private) method.

Now my queries.

1. I have above doubts in the project (that might be using Apple's private methods).
2. Is this code safe for apple store approval ?
3. If 2's answer is wrong, what should be done for horizontal page curl ?

In short, I want a horizontal page curl, and need your suggestions for having the proper solution, which might not trouble me in future.

Comment: I found the same link and i start to develop on it, but now I'm understanding that i will be in trouble in the future... did you find another solution for the curl effect touch controlled ?

Comment: It looks like this question is reliant on a zip file of code, which is now no longer available. I have removed those links, and I am now not sure the question is able to stand on its own - what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAFilter is private API, that's why you see compiler errors and warnings. What's worse is that Apple *may* reject your application for use of private API.

Comment: *will*. Easily detected private APIs are checked automatically.

Comment: Should I delete my question ?

Comment: I don't think that asking about private API is subject to prosecution. This is not Fight Club, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Some fantastic work on this topic at this blog, and a couple great github projects linked: http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html