# What is CAFilter on Oleb's Document

Tags: ios, pdf

The WebSite "http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/" shows how can we page curl effect like ibooks.

```
@class CAFilter;
extern NSString *kCAFilterPageCurl; // From QuartzCore.framework
static CAFilter *filter = nil;
...
```

Where the CAFilter class defined. Can't we look the body of this class?

Cant't we inherit this class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal page curl in iPhone - I have - But Valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879706/horizontal-page-curl-in-iphone-i-have-but-valid)

Comment: As pointed out in the linked question, CAFilter is private API and is not allowed in an App Store application.  It is not publicly defined in iOS 4.x or below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get CAFilter.h code from

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/CAFilter.h

In Your Project create one header file then copy this code.