# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown

Tags: iphone

is there any UIView animation  method curl from left or right 
Such UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

if not der what should i do for view Animation for curl left and right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this post : [iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions)