# MPMoviePlayerController in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Im developing a cocos2d application, im trying to integrate MPMoviePlayerController in my application. I added MPMoviePlayerController as subview [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubView:movie.view].

The is movie getting added on nicely.

Now i want to add page curl effect to movie view, when the user swipes the movie it should turn as page curl effect. I tried using UISwipeGestureRecognizer to add swipe gesture on top of movie view, but im not able to get the page curl effect on the movie. Could you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.
--Satish

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to Cocos2D's CCPageTurn3D action. In that case you should know that you can't apply Cocos2D animations (actions) to UIKit views such as the movie player.

You will have to use regular UIKit animations. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions) may contain the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I initially tried using CCPageTurn3D, realized doesn't work (like you mentioned above). I did try using UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp on the movie view, im not getting the desired result. Below is the function to flip
-(void)flip
{
         [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [UIView        setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:theMovie.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
I'm not getting the curl effect, also the movie view is not getting dismissed.