# IOS: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp from right to left

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, orientation

How do I get `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` transition to work from right to left, and `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you can do it out of the box. You can implement your own using Core Graphics transformations or Core Animation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions) shows you some basic implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried all samples from the topic, but it didn't helped for my case. I tried containter view and property @transform, but it didn't change transformation direction. My application works in landspace and I wand curl transation from right to left like in books.

Answer (score 0):

You can use New "Page Based Application" Provided by Apple, which will give you full control on viewing things as pages and in flipping from either left to right or right to left.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: Yes, it's nice solution, but I want to support IOS 3.1 and UIPageViewController requires IOS 5.