# Custom Segue with Page Curl and custom direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to push a view controller with a Page Curl animation. I've created a Custom Segue that works:

```
- (void) perform {

UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;    

[UIView transitionFromView:src.view
                    toView:dst.view
                  duration:0.6
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                }
 ];
}
```

The problem comes when I try to change the direction of the curl. I tryed using a container more or less like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions). But can't get it to work either.

```
- (void) perform
{
    
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;    
    
    UIView* parent = src.navigationController.view;
    UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parent.frame];
    
    [parent addSubview:containerView];
    containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    [containerView addSubview:src.view];
    src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
    
    [UIView transitionFromView:containerView
                        toView:dst.view
                      duration:0.6
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                    }
     ];
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: The transition you coded shows up for me, but the destinationVC doesn't accept interaction afterwards, as if it's frozen.