# Page curl animation from left bottom corner instead of right bottom corner on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

I need page curl animation from left bottom corner.

When I write below code page will animating from right bottom corner. But how can I do this if I need same effect from bottom left corner.

Thanks!

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:
 UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:_imagePreviewView cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/NSSakly/SKNCurlAnimation). animation with all corner managemeent